# Why does typescript think my property could be void after I throw in a promise catch block?

Tags: typescript, promise

```
async function fetchMpdData(mpdUrl: string): Promise<MPDFileContainer> {
  const data = await fetch(mpdUrl)
    .then((response): Promise<string> => response.text())
    .catch(
      (error): void => {
        throw new FetchError(`Error fetching file ${mpdUrl}: ${error}`);
      },
    );
  return parseStringMpd(data);
}
```

`parseStringMpd` takes a string.  The `data` passed to `parseStringMpd` is failing with:

> Argument of type 'string | void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

There are a [few other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167668/type-void-is-not-assignable-to-object) on SO that talk about how if the promise fails the catch block will cause the `data` property to be void.  But in my case the catch block is throwing an error.  So the data that is being complained about will never be reached.

Is the typescript parser just not able to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
  (error): void => {
    throw new FetchError(`Error fetching file ${mpdUrl}: ${error}`);
  },
```

You declare that the return type is `void` (a function that returns nothing) instead of `never` (a function that never returns). You could change it to `: never` but I suggest you to let TypeScript infer it:

```
  error => {
    throw new FetchError(`Error fetching file ${mpdUrl}: ${error}`);
  },
```

… But if you use `async` / `await` you could rewrite your code with them:

```
async function fetchMpdData(mpdUrl: string): Promise<MPDFileContainer> {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(mpdUrl)
        const data = await response.text()
        return parseStringMpd(data);
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(`Error fetching file ${mpdUrl}: ${error}`)
    }
}
```

Notice that variables `response` and `data` are correctly typed by inference. It's useless to declare their types.

Comment: And this is how I finally learned what `never` is useful for! Hah. Thanks.